# sending mail using java with some tweaking

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I have a project ( developed using java,apache tomcat, spring, hibernate) in which there is a functionality to show a puzzle with 10 questions to the end user.

The requirement is to send a mail to admin only when the user answers the first question.

Each questions is shown with 4 options out of which 1 is correct. His answers are directed to a method which checks whether the answer is correct or not. In the same method we have added the functionality to send a mail.

The problem is, mail should go to the admin only when the user answers the first question but mail is going to admin for each question the user answers.

Is there any tweaking to send a mail only when the user answers the first question and not for every question answered?

Comment: Show the part of the code you have tried, and specify what exact problem you are facing in code.

Comment: There is no problem in code. Answer comes to this method    

validateAnswer(){
//code to check answer correct or wrong

//code to send mail

}

Each question answered comes to validateAnswer() method. So mail is going 10 times as there are 10 questions in a puzzle. The requirement is to send mail only when the first question is answered.

Comment: We can't help you if you don't give us anything to work from. It certainly is possible to get it to send the e-mail after the first question, but we need more knowledge on how your code is structured. Is there a separate Question class, or is it all in one method and things like that

Comment: I am new to this website and facing difficulty to format the code. There is only one method to validate the answer.  The requirement is to send a mail only after first question is answered.

Comment: Just paste it. Somebody will correct the formatting if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Have a boolean variable in your code called `boolean isOnFirstAnswer = true`. When you call your `validateAnswer()` method, include the following if statement around the code which sends your e-mail

```
if (isOnFirstAnswer) {
    sendEmail();
    isOnFirstAnswer = false;
}
```

When the code runs for the first time, it will go into this if statement and send the e-mail. On all later calls to this method, `isOnFirstAnswer` is set equal to false, so the if statement evaluates to false and the e-mail is not sent.